# Navigation.PushModalAsync() does not trigger OnAppearing() in MAUI

Tags: maui

I have two pages (ProductListPage.xaml and ProductDetailsPage.xaml) and in the Product Details Page, the customer will place the order and if successful will be navigated back to the Product List Page using:

```cs
await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
```

In the Product List Page, I have the `OnAppearing()` override that should be triggered to show the shopping cart but it is not and not sure why?

```cs
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{           
    base.OnAppearing();
    var response = await ApiService.GetTotalCartItems(Preferences.Get("userId", 0));
    int totalItems = response.totalItems; 
    
    if (totalItems > 0) goToCart.IsVisible = true;
}
```

I placed a breakpoint at the `OnAppearing()` method to verify at runtime if it gets triggered or not and it was not. Is this a bug in .NET MAUI or I'm missing something?

Comment: Could be a bug, there are [a few issues](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+OnAppearing) in the official GitHub repository regarding the `OnAppearing()` overrides.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, is there an alternative approach?

Comment: First of all, I don't know if it's a bug in MAUI, I only pointed put that it could be, because there are quite few related to `OnAppearing()`. Secondly, I don't quite know what you're trying to achieve. For an alternative solution to your problem, you should update the question and explain in more detail what the behavior is that you're trying to achieve. From what I understand so far, you could make the API call also in the place where you're instantiating the Page.

Comment: Take it easy, i was asking a question :)

Comment: Relax, I know that. I was just letting you know that I need more information about your goal to help you.

Comment: Likely related to  [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8102). Its closed as fixed, but might not have made last month’s update cycle. Looks like there is workaround code you could download and try.

Comment: I tried to reproduce what you described, but unfortunately couldn't. I use `Navigation.PushModalAsync()` and `Navigation.PopModalAsync()` to navigate between two pages, the `OnAppearing()` method is triggered on both the first page and the modal page, you can tell me which platform you have encountered this problem ? I tested in Windows and iOS with no problems.

Comment: In android the issue was encountered.

Comment: I have just started experiencing this issue for the first time on Windows, so it's definitely a bug. Started after upgrading VS from 17.4.3 to 17.5.1. The previous bug reports were closed, so I've commented on the only one still left open - https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9531. It's only happenning intermittently, so there isn't anything you can do except hope it doesn't happen and wait for a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in my comments, this is an intermittent issue that won't be fully resolved until the MAUI team are able to reproduce and fix it, but I did think of a workaround solution, so I'll put that here as an interim answer... if you want to go to this much effort rewriting your code (rather than waiting for the fix).

Just before you call PopModalAsync, fire an event, and in your page which has the buggy OnAppearing subscribe to that event and put your logic there, instead of, or in addition to, having it in the OnAppearing (or use some other way to communicate between those 2 pages). OnAppearing is dodgy for now, so it's either implement an alternative approach or wait for a fix.

Edited to add: There is now a workaround available from the MAUI team. Details at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8102#issuecomment-1401093844

Edited again to add: Turns out there's actually multiple issues with OnAppearing at the moment, so this first work-around I have linked to may not work, however, in regards to another OnAppearing issue, there is a fix for that, and it's currently available in a .NET8 preview, and being backported to .NET7. See https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/13177

Comment: Setting the AppShell as a navigation page resolved the issue: MainPage = new NavigationPage(new AppShell()). But you are saying this is not necessary once the MAUI  team solve the issue.

Comment: Hi. If it's working for you you got lucky. I found out yesterday that they have a workaround, but the fix won't be available until the next service release (when-ever that is). Details of the workaround can be found at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8102#issuecomment-1401093844

Answer (score 1):

I have created a new project with the Maui App template. And there are two pages(MainPage.xaml and NewPage1.xaml).

In the MainPage:

```
      private async void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            count++;

            if (count == 1)
                  CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
            else
                  CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

            SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NewPage1());
      }

      protected async override void OnAppearing()
      {   // I added a breakpoint here
            base.OnAppearing();
      }
```

In the NewPage1:

```
      private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            await Navigation.PopModalAsync();// get back the MainPage
      }
```

The OnAppearing method's break point will be triggered every time when the MainPage displayed on the android. So you can create a new project to test my code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, can you please confirm which Visual Studio preview version you tested this on?

Comment: I tested it on the Visual Studio Community 14.0 Preview 2.1. @AliAlfaraj

Comment: And I tested it on the android 12 emulator. Did you test it on the sepcial physical device? @AliAlfaraj

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022 17.6.0 Preview 1.0 and this the lates update i can do. I did the testing in Android emulator and on the physical device.

Comment: Setting the main page as a Navigation Page solved the problem. Not sure why though.

Comment: Note my main page is an AppSehll, is it correct to set AppShell as a Navigation Page?

Comment: Yes, the default navigation in the Maui is AppShell, but you can also us the NavigationPage. @AliAlfaraj

Comment: I have tested. In the App.cs, the `MainPage = new AppShell()` and `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage())` both worked. @AliAlfaraj

Comment: Your code is correct but the bug is still there, and it only happens intermittently (I haven't noticed any patterns to it yet), so this isn't actually a solution to the issue. I have commented to this effect on the only MAUI OnAppearing issue still open https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9531 - all we can do is hope it doesn't happen and wait for a fix.